# Custom Drupal Analytics with Views- how to track the number of users by role over time?

Tags: users, nodes

I am building a social networking website in Drupal.  As users complete their profile, they are awarded different roles.  Now that I have launched the site and have some members, I would like to track the number of users by role over time so that I can see how my site is growing.

I built a view to do this and it shows me the information I want.  However, since I want to measure membership growth I would like to do this over time.  So, currently I simply log into my site and then type the numbers I need into Excel.

Is there a better way to do this?  Ideally, I would like to automatically save an Excel-ready snapshot every week (or in a dream world, have a graph automatically prepared).  Is there some other way (even without views) to track the number of users by role over time?

Comment: i suspect there is no out-of-the box solution ... I keep thinking about improving the "BI" in drupal lately a lot, probably creating something like a new module called "views result persist" would make sense :). The first phase (taking a view and saving its results into a table) should be pretty easy. Creating / altering the table automatically according to changes in the view would be harder :). The results could then be displayed with [forena](http://drupal.org/project/forena) which should [allready allow](http://drupal.org/node/828458) some charts :).

Answer (score 1):

You should record custom variables in Google Analytics. Download the GA Module https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics and Tokens
https://www.drupal.org/project/token
in the bottom of the configuration [yoursite].com/admin/config/system/googleanalytics 
expand the SHOWCUSTOM DIMENSIONS section
populate the values with tokens like [current-user:roles]
You can also record an event upon account creation which identifies the type of account
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events
you can do a JS event on submit that will record or it probably makes more sense to create a library to record all instances of certain types the way Google Developers is implying.